# Custom theme - Customize nested components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

I am implementing a custom theme and I would like to customize the font size of Menu items.
I can see that this tree:

ul (MuiMenu-list)
MuiListItem-root
MuiListItemText-root

If I want to customize the three components, I have to implement overrides for these three components, but I don't want to override all `MuiListItemText-root` but only those in my `MuiMenu`.

So I am wondering, can I write something like this:

```
MuiMenu: {
  list: {
    padding: 0,

    "& > $MuiListItem$root": {
      // some other formatting here
      "&$MuiListItemText$root": {
        fontSize: 14,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I did some tries but I didn't found one working, so I am wondering if this is possible or no.

My workaround is to write it in a pure CSS way like:

```
MuiMenu: {
  list: {
    padding: 0,

    "& > li": {
      // some other formatting here
      "& > div > span": {
        fontSize: 14,
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But I would like a more `Material-Ui` solution if possible :D

Answer (score 0):

for this target the `MuiMenuItem`. List items inside the menu also have the class of `MuiMenuItem-root`. Styles in this will only apply inside the menu items in the menu.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides:{
    MuiMenuItem:{
      root:{
        color:'red',
        fontSize:14
      }
    }
  }
})
```

Working demo:
[image: Edit Material demo (forked)]